# Python mapping all files inside a folder

Tags: python, file, list, mapping, directory

Hello I am writing a Python Script that will map to a list (or any other object) and each cell of the list will have 6 items in it :

1. path of file.
2. name of file (without the whole path).
3. the extension.
4. creation time.
5. last modified time.
6. it's md5 hash.

I am kind of new to python, I tried everything I know ...

Any Help?

Thanks :)

Comment: "I am kind of new to python, I tried everything I know ..." What did you try? And what failed?

Comment: I'm not on my computer right now ... But I trust my knowledge that what i have done is quite frankly nothing that worth something ...

Comment: @pyDan -- even if you think your attempts aren't worth talking about, you should still post them here anyways. People on StackOverflow tend to respond negatively when it doesn't appear as if the question asker put in effort into trying to solve their problem on their own. The best way to counter-act that would then be to always include what you've tried, what errors were raised, etc. Plus, if you show your code, people on StackOverflow can better understand what your mistakes were, what you were trying to do, and offer helpful tips in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh come on, go on google search for "python show file information" the first thing that appears is:

[Getting Information About a File](http://effbot.org/zone/python-fileinfo.htm)

```
This function takes the name of a file, and returns a 10-member tuple with the following contents:

(mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime)
```

Then you go to python's documentation and you'll find what the parameters mean:

[os.stat](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat)

```
st_mode - protection bits,
st_ino - inode number,
st_dev - device,
st_nlink - number of hard links,
st_uid - user id of owner,
st_gid - group id of owner,
st_size - size of file, in bytes,
st_atime - time of most recent access,
st_mtime - time of most recent content modification,
st_ctime - platform dependent; time of most recent metadata change on Unix, or the time of creation on Windows)
```

Then you go to see how to list a dir function, which is also in the documentation named `listdir`. Don't tell me that was hard it cost me 1 min.

This is how to traverse trough folders with DFS (Depth-first search):

```
import os 

def list_dir(dir_name, traversed = [], results = []): 
    dirs = os.listdir(dir_name)
    if dirs:
        for f in dirs:
            new_dir = dir_name + f + '/'
            if os.path.isdir(new_dir) and new_dir not in traversed:
                traversed.append(new_dir)
                list_dir(new_dir, traversed, results)
            else:
                results.append([new_dir[:-1], os.stat(new_dir[:-1])])  
    return results

dir_name = '../c_the_hard_way/Valgrind/' # sample dir
for file_name, stat in list_dir(dir_name):
    print file_name, stat.st_size # sample with file size
```

I'll leave the rest of it to you.

Comment: Believe me that i have tried many ways, but something always wrong. I think you misunderstood me , the way way hard part for me is how to map all the files. The much easy part is to get the states.

Comment: Try my code, but you need to use another array for the files.

Comment: First of all, Thanks for the help! Really appreciated. Seconds, I kind of understood what you have done in this script, But again, I'm not so good with python, your help is great and really improves my understanding of python and practicing.. Could you show me how to add the array with stats? I hope you will get how much you helped me :) Thanks again :)

Comment: Well i updated the code, but if you think that you are not good in python try reading http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/

Comment: Amazing ! Great my friend